# How to validate Google Bearer Token?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-workspace, google-chat

I have a chat app in Google Workspace that uses a Google Cloud Function as its back-end. The cloud function can currently be invoked without authentication. It has to be this way because the credentials sent by chat are not compatible with IAM policies.
So, I have to verify authentication by extracting and validating the bearer token sent with the request. My issue is that whenever I attempt to verify the token, I get this error:

```bash
No pem found for envelope {"alg":"RS256","kid":"e8196fb03ecdc8f203075ae13d9fbaf98d2dac3d","typ":"JWT"}
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
const googleapis = require("googleapis");
const { google } = googleapis;

function getToken(bearerToken) {
  return bearerToken.split(" ")[1];
}

async function verifyIdToken(token, aud) {
  const client = new google.auth.OAuth2();
  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
    idToken: token,
    audience: aud,
  });
  return ticket.getPayload();
}

exports.helloChat = async function helloChat(req, res){

  const token  = getToken(req.headers.authorization)
  const payload = await verifyIdToken(token)

}
```

Here is a [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/chat/quickstart/gcf-app) that shows all of the steps I have taken.
It does not include validating the token in cloud function.

Comment: After your edit. The tutorial does not mention any token or authorization. I have no idea what token you have. There are three types in Google Cloud: a) OAuth Access Token; b) OIDC Identity Token; c) JWT Assertion. I would need to see the token to decode it.

Comment: Use the following command, replacing TOKEN with your token, to see if details are returned. If it works, you have an OAuth Access Token. `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo`

Comment: I think this is the public certificate for the token: https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/chat@system.gserviceaccount.com Note that the URL also contains the service account email address `chat@system.gserviceaccount.com`. You might have to write your own verification code. On my personal blog, I show how to do that in Python. I am certain you can find examples written in node.js.

Comment: Whatis the `kid` in the error message? That is not a secret to worry about.

Comment: The `kid` is e8196fb03ecdc8f203075ae13d9fbaf98d2dac3d

Comment: `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo` returns `{
  "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}`

Comment: The Public Certificate in my previous comment matches the `kid`. Now we know which principal (service account) created the token. Since I cannot see the token, I do not know what you have.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this thanks to @John and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55698775/10633402) answer

```
import { decode, verify } from "jsonwebtoken";

async function getGooglePublicKeys() {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/chat@system.gserviceaccount.com"
  );
  const keys = await response.json();
  return keys as { [key: string]: string };
}

async function main(){
  const googlePublicKeys = await getGooglePublicKeys();
  
  const decodedToken = decode(token, { complete: true });
  const header = jwt?.header;
  const kid = header?.kid ?? "";

  if (!googlePublicKeys[kid]) {
    return;
  }
  
  const publicKey = googlePublicKeys[kid];

  try {
    const payload = verify(token, publicKey);
    console.log(payload);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An OIDC Identity Token consists of three base64 parts concatenated by periods:

```
token = base64(header) + '.' + base64(payload) + '.' + base64(signature)
```

This error is displaying the base64 decoded header:

```
No pem found for envelope: {"alg":"RS256","kid":..
```

Your code works correctly for me. Verify that this line of code is returning a valid OIDC Identity Token:

```
const token  = getToken(req.headers.authorization)
```

The first few characters of the token will start with `ey`. Your example header starts with `{"alg"` which when base64 encoded starts with `eyJhbGci`.

You can have Google verify an identity token using this command. Replace ID_TOKEN with the OIDC Identity Token. The endpoint also works in the web browser.

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=ID_TOKEN
```

Comment: I have tried this url before. I always end up with this response:
{
error_description: "Invalid Value"
}

Comment: @prismo That means the token is not a Google OIDC Identity Token. Edit your post and show how you are creating it.

Comment: I am not creating the token. The token is sent from the chat app along with a user's message.